Is there any alternative for webbrowser module that it will work in cloud run?
Assume the following code. I want to replace webbrowser because it does not work when I deploy my app in cloud run.
Ideally, when the button is clicked, I would like to open a new tab in the browser which the user currently uses for the app.
import chainlit as cl
import webbrowser


@cl.action_callback("Open tab")
async def on_action(action: cl.Action):
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    webbrowser.open(url, new=2)


@cl.on_message
async def on_message(message: cl.Message):
    response = f"Hello, you just sent: {message.content}!"
    actions = [
        cl.Action(name="Open tab", value="example_value")
    ]
    msg = cl.Message(content=response, actions=actions)
    await msg.send()

The code works locally but there is no new tab opened when the app is deployed to cloud run.
